# How to check Isolated Storage of Windows 10 mobile emulator?

Tags: c#, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I am currently working on Windows 10 and my requirement is to check isolated storage of Windows 10 Mobile emulator. With Windows Phone 8/8.1, its possible using IsolatedExplorerTool which we can use using Command Prompt. Can anyone suggest, how I can achieve the same for Windows 10 Emulator ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The IsolatedStorageExplorer tool (ISE) for WP8.1 works just fine with W10m apps (you will find it at *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool*).

You probably know how to use it, but just in case someone needs some explanation:

You will have to run it from command prompt or powershell. All you have to know is which emulator you are using and your app's package name. The first is obvious, the second you will find in manifest file:

[image]

In case you want to get the storage of mobile and the name of the app is different type than GUID, you will have to view code for manifest file (right click -> view code) and get *PhoneProductID*.

Then it goes like this:

- first make sure which emulator index you use - run:

  ```
  .\ISETool.exe EnumerateDevices
  ```

  and you should see something like this:
  [image]
- to download your *IsolatedStorage* from emulator, use this line:

  ```
  .\ISETool.exe ts deviceindex:4 95fbf894-0aee-4398-b2e3-0f8eed69357c C:\Data\
  ```

  where `C:\Data\` is your target folder.
- to upload your data use similar command:

  ```
  .\ISETool.exe rs deviceindex:4 95fbf894-0aee-4398-b2e3-0f8eed69357c C:\Data\
  ```

  now `C:\Data\` is your source folder.

Type `.\ISETool.exe` to see more help and examples.

Comment: Thanks, @Romasz. Can you also tell me where we can find Windows 10 icons that I can use in App bar, like for Windows Phone 8/8.1 we get in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Icons

Comment: I don't have a UUID in the Package name, but the app name instead.

 If I use the UUID from the Package.appxmanifest file and try to give the same command to a Lumia 635 device running Windows 10 Mobile, I get error "Access denied".

Ideas?

Comment: @JohanPaul View code for *package.appxmanifest* (right click -> view code), you will find there *PhoneProductId* - have you tried with this one?

Comment: @Romasz Yes, I used that as the UUID but got "Access Denied" when trying that with ISETool. Should it work anyway?

Comment: @JohanPaul Not sure right now, maybe I will find some time todays evening to test it. Also have you tried to generate new guid and put in the Identity Name?

Comment: @JohanPaul As far as I've tried, first I also got exceptions about GUID required and access denied, but when I've reinstalled the app by VS and then used ISE with PhoneProductID - it works.