# Local Storage explorer for W10 mobile

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am looking for a tool like [Isolated Storage Spy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) to be able to access the Local Storage of applications I am developing for windows 10 mobile.

In other words is there any tool with or without a GUI that enables access to Local Storage for applications in W10 mobile?

Comment: IsoStoreSpy can be used for Windows 10 mobile apps. See the similar question [Accessing storage of simulator/device while debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036398/accessing-storage-of-simulator-device-while-debugging).

Comment: @Jay Zuo. Thanks a lot. As soon as I check this works I will update my answer.

Comment: @Jay Zuo. You are right. IsoStoreSpy works for windows 10 mobile. If you would like to make your comment into an answer please do so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought [IsoStoreSpy](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) is designed for Windows Phone 8 & 8.1 apps, but it can be also used for Windows 10 Mobile apps. To use it, we can download it form [here](http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/releases/view/121759).

Besides IsoStoreSpy, we can also use [Windows Phone Power Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/). This is also a GUI tool that can be used for Windows 10 Mobile apps. With these two tools, we can access Local, Temporary and Roaming Folder.

Also as @Alexej siad, Isolated Storage Explorer (ISETool.exe) for Windows Phone 8.1 works just fine with Windows 10 Mobile apps. It is installed in the following location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool

The usage of this tool is like [How to use the Isolated Storage Explorer tool for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx). However for Windows Phone 8.1, it adds a `<appxfolder:[root]>` option for user to select Local, Roaming or Temp Folder.

```regex
<appxfolder:[root]> - Specifies the isolated store root for appx packages.
                    root can be one of the following (If root is not
                    specified, it's assumed to be "Local" by default):
Local             - Local store root
Roaming           - Roaming store root
Temp              - Temp store root
```

For more help and examples just type `ISETool.exe` in command-line.

Comment: I do not have this folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\IsolatedStorageExplorerTool

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any UWP application like IsoStoreSpy or file browser of Windows Phone Power Tools. I think they are not yet ported to Win 10.
If you are developing on PC (sure you are) you can try get access application folder directly.

One more thing that you can try is command line [ISETool.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408(v=vs.105).aspx) (not sure that it would be working with UWP, but there is a chance)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the PC part of the application I am indeed accessing the application folder. I was just wondering if there was a tool to do the same for the phone. I don't believe there is an difference between PC and phone when handling local storage but one needs to check to be sure.