# Using JSON.NET to write Json file in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, json, file, uwp

I'm pretty new to file handling in UWP, and it feels really intricate. I don't know how to start. I thought about "learn by doing": I failed miserably.

**The goal:**
I would like store an object into a Json file, into a well known location. My object is of type "`MySettings`" and I would like to save it, for instance, to `"ms-appx:///myconfig.json"`.

How can I do it?

**Another question:** will this file be editable from outside my application easily, like in classic Desktop applications? I thought about editing the settings with a text editor, for changing settings quickly without rebuilding my app.

Comment: Try use  NewtoJson and the first is to open the file to read the json to instance .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ms-appx:///` represents app's install directory which is read-only. So we can't a store Json file in such location. I'd suggest you store Json files in application data locations such as app's local data folder (`ms-appdata:///local/`). For more info, please see [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). And following is a simple sample with using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

// serialize JSON to a string
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);

// write string to a file
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myconfig.json");
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, json);
```

Once the file is stored, you should be able to find it under
**`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\{Package family name}\LocalState`** folder and you can edit it with a text editor easily. For more info, you may refer to [my previous answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056140/5506161).