# Windows Universal App - Javascript - File IO - No Response

Tags: javascript, file-io, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a file saving function:

```
function WINJSWrite(file, content) {
    if (content.length <= 0) {
        GameConsts.MyAlert("No data to save.");
    }

    // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
    Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.deferUpdates(file);
    // write to file
    Windows.Storage.FileIO.writeTextAsync(file, content).done(function () {
        // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
        // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
        Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.completeUpdatesAsync(file).done(function (updateStatus) {
            if (updateStatus === Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.complete) {
                //WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " was saved.", "sample", "status");
            } else {
                //WinJS.log && WinJS.log("File " + file.name + " couldn't be saved.", "sample", "status");
            }
        });
});
```

};

Then I call this as follows, depending on whether `myfile.txt` exists or not:

```
localFolder.getFileAsync('myfile.txt').then(
        function (file) {
            // NEVER GETS HERE
            if (file) {
                WINJSWrite(file, content);
            } else {
                localFolder.createFileAsync("myfile.txt").done(
                    function (newFile) {
                        if (newFile) {
                            WINJSWrite(newFile, content);
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
```

But the code never gets to `// NEVER GETS HERE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: if I use `localFolder.getFileAsync('myfile.txt').done(` instead of `localFolder.getFileAsync('myfile.txt').then(`, then it throws an error saying the file is not there (but I know it is).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of differences between [**then**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR229728) and [**done**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701079) method. One of them is that

> Unhandled exceptions in a **then** function are **silently captured** as part of the state of the promise, but unhandled exceptions in a **done** function are **thrown**. Both functions can handle exceptions that have been passed to them as part of the state of a promise.

And for [GetFileAsync(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder#Windows_Storage_StorageFolder_GetFileAsync_System_String_) method, it returns a [StorageFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile) that represents the specified file only when this method completes successfully. If there is no such file, it will throw an error. So when you use **done** instead of **then**,you can get the error.

To solve this problem, we can change the code like the following as both functions can handle exceptions.

```
localFolder.getFileAsync('myfile.txt').done(
    function onComplete(file) {
        WINJSWrite(file, content);
    }, function onError() {
        localFolder.createFileAsync("myfile.txt").done(
            function (newFile) {
                WINJSWrite(newFile, content);
            });
    });
```

For more info, please see [Quickstart: Using promises](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700339.aspx). Besides, you can also refer to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36056140/5506161) to check if the file is under local folder.