# Accessing application storage using IsoStoreSpy on Windows 10 mobile doesn't work

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I have problem accessing application storage using IsoStoreSpy. During testing of our logger mechanism on Windows 10 Mobile, QA had error accessing the storage to get logs using IsoStoreSpy 3.0 which surprised me that it did not work. I checked on the my phone and confirmed that IsoStoreSpy did not work.

I also tested accessing storage using:

- Windows Phone Power Tools
- ISETool.exe from SDK

All of them returned error when accessing the storage. In question [How to check Isolated Storage of Windows 10 mobile emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063136/how-to-check-isolated-storage-of-windows-10-mobile-emulator?noredirect=1&lq=1) there was the solution to reinstall the app using Visual Studio. It indeed worked, but this is not the solution because we need to access the application's storage without using VS. This program was sideloaded.

I've tried to access application storage using the path. One was read it from the program using

```
 StorageFolder appInstalledFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
 PropertyToBeDisplayedOnTheScreen = appInstalledFolder.Path;
```

To access the path I used http://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-10-mobile-insider-preview/358307-access-c-root-windows-10-mobile-file-explorer.html to get the C: drive then to access application storage, but I could not get to that folder. It is possible to access the folder by using method from http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/guide-filesystem-access-sftp-windows-10-t3185766 but it is not good because requires system modification.

My question is are there other method to access the storage like IsoStoreSpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use **[App File Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal#app-file-explorer)** to view and manipulate files stored by your sideloaded apps. This tool should be able to work no matter your application is deployed in Debug mode or Release mode.

To use this feature, we need turn on [device discovery and pairing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile#turn-on-device-discovery-and-pairing) and also **Device Portal**. Then we can access application storage by browser like following:
[image]

For more info, please see [Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile) and also [Using the App File Explorer to see your app data](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/).